# Attribute relationship from Hierarchy in SSAS 2012

Tags: ssas, relationship, business-intelligence, olap, dimension

I have a misunderstood problem when trying to work with SSAS in creating and configuring Dimension. The problem is: My dimension named Author have three attributes (AuthorKey, AuthorID, AuthorState), which AuthorKey is the primary key of my dimension.

With Visual studio 2013, I have created a user-hierarchy like:

```
Hierarchy name: AuthorByState
 + AuthorState
 + AuthorKey
   - AuthorID
   - AuthorState
```

[image]

When I switched to Attribute Relationship tab, i have seen an auto-generated relationship like:

```
AuthorKey(AuthorID) --> AuthorState
```

[image]

My questions is: I understand that SSAS automatically relates every attribute in a dimension to the dimension key, but why does the AuthorID attribute is "inside" the AuthorKey attribute instead of "outside" as normally like AuthorState? What it means the attribute relationship?

Thanks for any explanation and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: I'll phrase the question a little differently.  **The second screenshot shows a scenario where two attribute relationships have been created: Author->AuthorId and Author->AuthorState.  Why does SSAS display these two relationships differently?**  I've even viewed the XML definition, and I can't see anything that's really different about the way the attribute relationships are defined that stands out.

Answer (score 1):

When you build a user-defined hierarchy (the thing you called AuthorsByState) then that causes the Attribute Relationship tab diagram to render differently. Basically any attribute that appears in a user-defined hierarchy has it's own bubble. If you were to build a second user-defined hierarchy with AuthorId in it, then AuthorId would have it's own bubble in the Attribute Relationships tab diagram.

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

Attributes in the hierarchy are not being defined correctly.

#### Symptoms

When you define a hierarchy, attributes which are not related are being dragged in

#### Solution

If you dimension has one key (the "Natural Key" - the key for business use only) - then that should be defined as your key (It clearly says that "Author" is your key, and I don't know what that field stand for).
If your dimension has two keys, a natural Key and surrogate key. The Natural key is the key with the business meaning (as every author has an id) and the surrogate key is the key that we allocate (an identity int or whatever).
Put the Surrogate key in the dimension. Define it as a key, and choose the "visible attribute" as the Name/Natural key. Once you do that the Hierarchy wouldn't drag unnecessary attribute inside that section.

A comment: if Author Key is your substitute Key and Author Id is your natural key you can hide Author Key; make it *display* Author Id instead in Properties->NameColumn

Please note the use of "date key" in the following post by Microsoft:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3414/sql-server-analysis-services-attribute-relationships/
As without it the Hierarchy just wouldn't be set.

Comment: I see this nesting occur even when both a hierarchy and attribute relationship is defined.  In fact, it will not show the nesting until an attribute relationship is defined.  Sometimes the attribute relationship is shown with a broken out arrow, and other times nested as in the OP's second screenshot. The Author->AuthorID(nested) shows there is already an attribute relationship.

Comment: Do you need "AuthorId" as an attribute? You have "author" so you can choose key and then DisplayField. You defined your key as an Author, but the key should actually be the AuthorID, shouldn't it?

Comment: Since the DSV on the right shows both AuthorKey and AuthorID, I assume AuthorID is the source system OLTP ID and AuthorKey(named Author in Dimension) is the OLAP Key.  AuthorID could be ommitted, but that doesn't answer the question of why some relationships are represented differently.  From what I can tell, it often does this with "leaf" relationships, where the child does not then relate to anymore attributes, but sometimes it decides to break them out even then.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Had it been Author Key (named Author) as key then it would process things as it should.

Comment: "process things as it should" The question is not about cube processing, or fixing anything that is not processing properly.  The question is why the relationship is represented differently. I'll quote the OP " why does the AuthorID attribute is "inside" the AuthorKey attribute instead of "outside" as normally like AuthorState? What it means the attribute relationship?"

Comment: I've edited my answer, please read and let me know what's unclear.